# libssl1.1 is deprecated in Ubuntu 22.04, what to do now?

Tags: 22.04, ssl

I tried to install [livebook](https://github.com/livebook-dev/livebook)
to use Elixir, but I could not install it.
Instead, I got this error message when trying to install a dependency:

```
> sudo apt install erlang-crypto
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 erlang-crypto : Depends: libssl1.1 (>= 1.1.1) but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

`libssl1.1` [is no longer](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=default&section=all&arch=any&keywords=libssl1.1&searchon=names) in the repositories of Ubuntu 22.04.

The [workaround](https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/installing-mongodb-over-ubuntu-22-04/159931/22) is to install it manually:

```
echo "deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-security main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/impish-security.list
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libssl1.1
```

but I am not sure if that approach will introduce vulnerabilities in my machine.

As far as I know, this issue have impacted other applications as well:

- [MongoDB](https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/installing-mongodb-over-ubuntu-22-04/159931/4)
- [MariaDB](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-28397)
- [espanso](https://github.com/espanso/espanso/issues/1056)
- [mosquitto](https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?t=198213)

So, can we do something about this or just wait for all those applications to be updated?

Comment: The version of erlang-crypto that comes with U 22.04 depends on libssl3. From what source are you trying to install erlang-crypto?

Comment: I used the source described in the [documentation for Ubuntu](https://elixir-lang.org/install.html): `wget https://packages.erlang-solutions.com/erlang-solutions_2.0_all.deb && sudo dpkg -i erlang-solutions_2.0_all.deb`. I think that is outdated. If you used the `elixir` package that comes with Ubuntu 22.04 is also a bit outdated (version 12) and is not enough for running Livebook (it requires version 13). At the end, I opted for installing both Erlang and Elixir using `asdf`.

Comment: If no dedicated .deb or PPA is available for Ubuntu 22.04, and you cannot make it work with the default version of Ubuntu (it is not that old), then your only option may be to compile yourself.